# "t" key is delayed and doesn't capitalize

Tags: keyboard

All of a sudden my "t" key is having issues. About half the time it simply doesn't work, other times it works but it prints delayed, so as I'm typing a sentence it will show up 3-4 characters too late, sometimes appearing in the next word.

It also won't capitalize. Holding shift (tried both of them) works with every key except "t." Caps lock results in every key being capitalized except the "t."

I have the same issue with an external mechanical keyboard so it's definitely not a hardware issue.

This is on a second generation Macbook (not Pro) wih macOS 10.14.3

Comment: can you include details of the model of macbook (year or model #). Not sure what 'second generation' is

Comment: @cmason it's Model A1534 EMC 2746

Comment: What year macbook?

Comment: A1534 EMC 2746 signifies an early-2015 12" MacBook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting PRAM and SMC seems to have done the trick...

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop is among those for which Apple issued a service notice regarding the keyboard:

> Apple has determined that a small percentage of the keyboards in certain MacBook and MacBook Pro models may exhibit one or more of the following behaviors:
>
> - Letters or characters repeat unexpectedly
> - Letters or characters do
>     not appear
> - Key(s) feel "sticky" or do not respond in a consistent
>     manner
>
> Apple or an Apple Authorized Service Provider will service eligible MacBook and MacBook Pro keyboards, free of charge. The type of service will be determined after the keyboard is examined and may involve the replacement of one or more keys or the whole keyboard.

I would recommend you contact Apple regarding this issue:

https://www.apple.com/support/keyboard-service-program-for-macbook-and-macbook-pro/