# How to fix one glitchy key (the 'r' key is wonky)

Tags: keyboard

The <kbd>r</kbd> key on my work laptop has developed an annoying behavior:

- sometimes the letter `r` does not appear when I type it
- other times, the letter `r` appears out of order in a word, such as `wodr`
- sometimes, the letter `r` repeats without me typing it twice

This happens in browser, emacs, terminal.

So it seems like this letter (and only this letter) is sometimes going into the queue in the wrrong order. Note the misspelled `wrong` in the previous sentence - I left that one in, but while typing this question I have corrected about 4 other `r`-related errors.

I've inspected the keyboard and it's fairly clean. No crumbs or gunk, and nothing really different about the `r` key compared to the other keys. The key doesn't seem to be physically slow or sticking.

It sounds like the issue described [here](https://support.apple.com/keyboard-service-program-for-mac-notebooks), but my macbook is not among the "eligible models".

Could this be the same issue as [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/352444/149574)?

Specs:

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
- Version 10.14.6 (18G9323)

Comment: Maybe a can of air spray might help? Had a similar issue with my volume up key, and cleaning did the job.

Answer (score 0):

I reset the PRAM based on instructions from [here](https://www.macworld.com/article/224955/how-to-reset-a-macs-nvram-pram-and-smc.html) and typing <kbd>r</kbd> seems to be more reliable.

I'll accept my own answer, but if the problem persists I'll update this to let future people know what worked and what did not.